# PHP Simple HTML DOM - file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages

Tags: php, ssl, simple-html-dom

I am going to extract the information of [this page](https://aasood.com/a02s-64gb-4gb.html) from an other domain using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser,
But unfortunately when I use  `file_get_html` or  `file_get_content` :

`$html = file_get_html('https://aasood.com/a02s-64gb-4gb.html');`

I get this error:

**file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed**

I do not own the aasood.com and I can not change its server.

Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid SSL problem with curl with no verify peer, although it is better you fix SSL problems.

```
$con = curl_init('https://aasood.com/a02s-64gb-4gb.html');
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($con);
curl_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
But when I do as you say:

`$con = curl_init('https://aasood.com/a02s-64gb-4gb.html');

curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_exec($con);

curl_close($con);
 
 if ($html !=''){

  if ($html->find("meta[itemprop='price']")) {`
I get this error:

**Call to a member function find() on string**

Comment: Be careful. Look at php.net and see that file_get_html does not exists, it is not a PHP function. And file_get_contents and curl return string, not an object. To parse HTML you can use DOMDocument::loadHTML (https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), which belongs to PHP standard.